# Unexpected behavior when placing Unicode text on Clipboard with NULL owner window

Tags: c++, winapi, clipboard

I'm trying to place text on the clipboard from a Windows desktop application that I'm working on, but I am getting some behavior I don't understand.

The function I'm using is as follows:

```
bool Clipboard::CopyText(const XStringW& txt)
{
    size_t memsize = sizeof(wchar_t) * (txt.Length() + 1);
    HGLOBAL glob = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, memsize);
    if (glob != NULL)
    {
        void* mem = GlobalLock(glob);
        if (mem != NULL)
        {
            memcpy(mem, (LPCWSTR) txt, memsize);
            GlobalUnlock(glob);

            HANDLE handle = NULL;

            if (OpenClipboard(NULL))
            {
                EmptyClipboard();
                handle = SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT, glob);
                ASSERT(handle != NULL);
                CloseClipboard();
            }

            return handle != NULL;
        }
        else
```

What happens after `else` is not especially important.

If I execute the above block of code, everything actually works as it should. This is strange to me, because according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-openclipboard):

> If an application calls OpenClipboard with hwnd set to NULL, EmptyClipboard sets the clipboard owner to NULL; this causes SetClipboardData to fail.

But I find that it's working as it should.

However, I only added `EmptyClipboard()` as an experiment. Prior to this, my code was not working properly. Let's say I placed the text `"Hello"` from a Word document. Then I copied a number `999` from my application. What would happen is, if I tried pasting to Excel or Word (for example), it would paste `"Hello"`. However if I selected `"Paste Special"` in (say) Excel and pasted as text, it would paste `"999"`. So it would work, but only if a non-default paste was used.

If I add in the `EmptyClipboard()` (as per my code above), it works perfectly. It clears whatever was there before. But it shouldn't, according to the documentation.

Can anybody help me understand?

Comment: Under [OpenClipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-openclipboard) find the text *"Is this page helpful?"*, click *"No"* and submit your feedback.

Comment: On a side note, if `SetClipboardData()` fails, the allocated `glob` is not owned by the clipboard and thus must be freed, but this code is not doing that, so the `glob` will be leaked.

Comment: Hi,I can reproduce this issue now. And I will confirm it with Internal engineer, and response here if there is any update.Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @RemyLebeau in this instance the assert immediately after setClipboardData() will fail before that happens.

Comment: @Nimo if the assert fails and throws an error, the `glob` will be leaked AND the clipboard will not be closed. If the assert does nothing (ie, release build) and `SetClipboardData()` fails, the `glob` is still leaked.

Comment: @rem The crucial point here is that an implementation written against the documented contract can cause a double-free: Under the assumption that `SetClipboardData` will fail given the preconditions, a client could `GlobalFree` the allocated data without observing `SetClipboardData`'s return value. While it may not be advisable to do so, that implementation would still be perfectly within the specification. Leaking data is bad, sure, but a double-free is usually an *exploitable* software defect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to respond to this question with anything other than:

> "Because the documentation says so." <sup>tm</sup>

and leave it at that. The documentation and the examples provided therein specifically state that you must call, in order* (pseudo-code):

```cpp
if(::OpenClipboard(hwnd)) {
    if(::EmptyClipboard()) {
        //Copy data...
        ::SetClipboardData(/*...*/)'
    }
    ::CloseClipboard();
}
```

Which also says basically: "Do not call EmptyClipboard without first calling OpenClipboard *with a proper handle to a window*".

Failing to do that and then wondering why it doesn't work is an exercise in frustration.

*<sub>There are cases where responding to specific WM messages should not call `::OpenClipboard` but they do not apply here.</sub>

Comment: I'm not wondering why it doesn't work, I'm wondering why it does when it shouldn't.

Comment: Read the question again. The OP isn't violating the contract and complaining that things don't work as expected. They are violating the documented contract, and things should fail, but they don't and everything works as desired, though the documentation *explicitly* states that one API call will fail.

Comment: In my experience, the paragraph in the documentation regarding a NULL window is simply wrong.

Comment: IMHO, it is like the usual UB warnings. The doc specifies how a programme **should** access the clipboard. That means that if you follow the doc, the program will work as expected. If you don't, nothing guarantees, that it will not work, but it could break after any update of any component, or even after a simple recompilation. Or it could put an unrelated component into an unuseable state. Exactly like invoking UB in C or C++ common sense.

Comment: @Nimo Same difference. It isn't behaving as expected, but in reality your expectations are flawed.

Comment: @ser There is no UB here. The documentation clearly states that an API call *will* fail under certain conditions. When you arrange for those conditions, the API call *does not* fail. This is very different from UB where things *that aren't documented to behave in any particular way* are free to exhibit any behavior.

Comment: *"your expectations are flawed"* - I don't see the flaw in expecting a system to behave as documented. Where's the flaw here?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a guess than a proper answer, but I did a couple of tests and found interesting results.
I had hypothesis that the way it suppose to work is to depend on the type of thread you are calling it from.

For example, if you call `OpenClipboard(NULL)` from windowless thread/process it should still work and give you access to clipboard. This would be logical, as you physically can't pass it any valid `HWND` whatsoever, as you don't have any.

But if you try to call `OpenClipboard(NULL)` from a thread/process that actually has active, visible window it *should* fail, as you are just being lazy not passing that `HWND` that you definitely have on your hands.

This is the way it *should* work, as I see it. However, it seems, that even if they had this plan originally, at some point, Windows developers just ditched it due to some undisclosed reason, and made `OpenClipboard(NULL)` work regardless if you have windows or not, **without** updating the documentation...