# SetClipboardData and new operator for HANDLE

Tags: c++, winapi, clipboard

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE h = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, 4); //new char[4]{ "QWE" };
    if (!h) return 1;
    strcpy_s((char*)h, 4, "QWE");
    OpenClipboard(0);
    EmptyClipboard();
    SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, h);
    CloseClipboard();
    HeapFree(h, 0, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

If I use `new char[4]{ "QWE" };` instead of `HeapAlloc()` I recieve an error upon `SetClipboardData()` execution. Why does this work this way? Memory inspector for `h` shows the same result in both cases.

Comment: `strcpy_s((char*)h, 4, "QWE");` this looks fishy: it should be `char *h = HeapAlloc(...` ...`strcpy_s(h, 4, ...`

Comment: if i comment `strcpy_s((char*)h, 4, "QWE");` this change nothing.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264137/how-to-copy-string-to-clipboard-in-c

Comment: I still can't find an answer for my question: Why does `HeapAlloc` works and `new char` doesn't, if memory is the same in the memory inspector?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setclipboarddata says "If SetClipboardData succeeds, the system owns the object identified by the hMem parameter." which indicates the memory needs to have been allocated the way the system expects. While I don't have a definitive reference on this handy, the general idea is that the Windows API doesn't know about `new` and can't take ownership of memory allocated by it. So the memory needs to have been allocated by Windows API mechanisms.

Comment: Why do you want to use new or HeapAlloc? a HANDLE is not a memory pointer (sometimes it is but it's an implementation detail). Just use GlobalAlloc with GMEM_MOVEABLE like what's demonstrated by official doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard

Comment: @the A reference isn't required, this can be answered using logical reasoning alone. `operator new` can be implemented by any given C++ implementation any which way. Since the Windows API doesn't know about every single C++ compiler (past, present, and future) it certainly cannot know every implementation detail about any given C++ compiler.

Comment: Patient: "Doctor, it hurts if I do this." - Doctor: "Don't do this."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy string to clipboard in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264137/how-to-copy-string-to-clipboard-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HeapAlloc()` returns an `LPVOID` (`void*`) pointer, whereas `new char[]` returns a `char*` pointer. They are NOT the same type, and neither of them is a valid Win32 `HANDLE` to a memory object.

`SetClipboardData()` wants a valid `HANDLE` pointing to a memory object, but not just *any* type of `HANDLE`. Per the [`SetClipboardData()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setclipboarddata):

> **If `SetClipboardData` succeeds, the system owns the object identified by the `hMem` parameter.** The application may not write to or free the data once ownership has been transferred to the system, but it can lock and read from the data until the `CloseClipboard` function is called. (The memory must be unlocked before the Clipboard is closed.) **If the `hMem` parameter identifies a memory object, the object must have been allocated using the [`GlobalAlloc`] function with the `GMEM_MOVEABLE` flag.**

Neither `HeapAlloc()` nor `new[]` satisfy those requirements. You MUST use `GlobalAlloc()` instead, so the clipboard can properly take ownership of the memory object, eg:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE h = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVABLE, 4);
    if (!h) return 1;

    char *pmem = (char*) GlobalLock(h);
    if (!pmem) {
        GlobalFree(h);
        return 1;
    }

    strcpy_s(pmem, 4, "QWE");
    GlobalUnlock(h);

    if (OpenClipboard(NULL)) {
        EmptyClipboard();
        if (SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, h))
            h = NULL; // clipboard now owns it, don't free it!
        CloseClipboard();
    }

    if (h) GlobalFree(h);
    return 0;
}
```

At *compile-time*, `HANDLE` is just an alias for `void*`, and a `char*` pointer is implicitly convertible to `void*`, so the *compiler* will allow a `HeapAlloc`'ed `LPVOID` or a `new[]`'ed `char*` to be passed to `SetClipboardData()` without complaining.  But at *run-time*, the *OS* expects the passed `HANDLE` to point at a valid movable global memory object, anything else will invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I still wonder why the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-openclipboard) doesn't get fixed (or whether this code is actually correct): *"If an application calls `OpenClipboard` with hwnd set to `NULL`, `EmptyClipboard` sets the clipboard owner to `NULL`; this causes `SetClipboardData` to fail."*

Comment: Agreed. I think it would fail only in a delay-rendering scenario, where an owner window is absolutely required, but outside of that, the owner window being null or not is moot, and I bet the API does allow it, but the docs don't reflect that.

Comment: Oops, misremembered the events. The question is still there, without an answer: [Unexpected behavior when placing Unicode text on Clipboard with NULL owner window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66475791/1889329).